# Removing multiple entries using SREM in ioredis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, redis, ioredis

I wonder what is the correct syntax to use in order to remove multiple entries using `SREM` command.

When I call:

```
const myKey = "myKey";
const entriesToRemove: string[] = ...

this.redisClient.srem(myKey, entriesToRemove);
```

I get:

`ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'srem' command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `entriesToRemove` sometimes was empty. Adding a lenght check solved the issue.